# Windows 7 Headphone Glitch

Tags: windows-7, headphones

For some reason, it seems my headphones will not work right in Windows 7. When I plug them in, the built-in speakers (I have a laptop) get silenced, but no sound comes out of the headphones. Windows doesn't show their muted or anything, and it seems to treat them and the built-in speakers as one device. I can get them to work if I put the computer in standby, then wake it up again. They're normal non-USB headphones, so I don't see how it could be a compatibility thing. They also work fine with my phone and under Ubuntu, which I have installed on the same machine. They'll also work fine if I plug them in while running Ubuntu, then reboot into Windows 7. What could be causing this, and I how could I permanently fix it?

**Update**: I found an option in Control Panel called 'IDT Audio Control Panel', although I couldn't find anything that might explain this.

Comment: We would need more information about your hardware.  For example, with the Realtek HD audio chipset on my motherboard, connecting headphones prompts you to acknowledge that headphones were in fact plugged in, and the AudioHD control panel (from Realtek) then gives me the option to choose to separate whether any audio out is separated by output, or sent as a single signal to all outputs.  Point being, there may be a setting you need to change in your chipset specific audio panel, or drivers you need to update, etc... which is why you should include more information on your hardware.